# Mobile Facebook share dialog not working properly on mobile browsers (iOS and Android)

Tags: facebook

I have a problem with the official embed of the share dialog here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

The code is this:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

If you open their page above in a mobile browser on iOS or Android, run the snippet ("Try it yourself" button), it opens the share window with the audience dropdown:

[image]

On iOS (Safari), the options "Your Page" and "Private Message" are not clickable, they don't work.

On Android (Chrome), only the "Your Page" option doesn't work.

Did you encounter this problem and **is there a fix for it?** Thank you.

Comment: File a bug on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks, I looked now and it's been recently reported:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1854950731465303/